# Time taken for keyboard to animate on iOS

Tags: iphone, keyboard

I know from what I have observed, and from what people are saying on the www, that the keyboard takes close to 0.3 seconds to appear on the iPhone. I have set my 'field-moving-out-of-the-way' animations to 0.3s, and they work well.

But is there a constant somewhere in the system that I can use instead of this hard-coded value?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
double animationDuration;
animationDuration = [[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] doubleValue];
```

is that what you mean?

Comment: You forgot to say that notification is one of the keyboard-related notifications (e.g. UIKeyboardWillShowNotification) and your code must be in the handler of that notification

Comment: What is the animation time?  Is it not constant?